# Are timeout/interval IDs ever recycled?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Are the IDs returned by `setTimeout` and `setInterval` ever recycled after they have completed (or have been cleared)? Or are all IDs unique for the life of the session?

Could calling `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval` on an old ID cause an unrelated timeout/interval to be cleared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers)

> Each object that implements the WindowTimers interface has a list of active timers. Each entry in this lists is identified by a number, which must be unique within the list for the lifetime of the object that implements the WindowTimers interface.

Comment: The actual answer to the question isn't very clear to me in this answer, since I don't know what exactly is meant by "the lifetime of the object that implements the WindowTimers interface". If that means the `window` object, I guess that means the answer is "no, they're not recycled in that browser tab until navigation". But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53127712/496046) shows some Blink internals, and if I'm reading it correctly, it *does* reuse timer IDs once the page has used about 2^31 timers. So I guess the browsers aren't following the spec and the real answer is "yes".

Comment: I don't see how that's helpful. If that's relevant to the answer, then mention it in the answer, otherwise the answer isn't complete. But to answer *your* question: I don't know exactly what the libraries I'm using are doing, and I don't know how long the page will be open. So the answer is maybe.